# Mongoose: how to structure a schema with a SET of subdocuments (one unique field)?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, upsert

I'm trying to make the following schema to work:

```
var FormSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    form_code: { type: String, unique: true },
    ...
});
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ...
    submissions: [{
        form_code: { type: String, unique: true },
        last_update: Date,
        questions: [{
            question_code: String,
            answers: [Number]
        }]
    }],
});
```

The rationale here is that a user can have many unique forms submitted, but only the last submission of each unique form should be saved. So, ideally, by pushing a submission subdocument when updating a user, the schema would either add the submission object to the set, or update the subdocument containing that `form_code`.

The following code doesn't work as desired (it pushes the new subdocument even if the `form_code` is already present):

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: user.id },
    { $addToSet: { submissions: submission_object } },
    function (err, user) {
        // will eventually have duplicates of form_code at user.submissions
    }
);
```

The above schema clearly doesn't work, what must be changed to achieve that "upsertToSet"?